# Pairwise independent hash function family?

Tags: probability-theory, hash

I am looking for a family of pairwise independent hash functions $\mathcal{H} = \{h \mid h:[n]\rightarrow [m]\}$ that is easily computable.

As an example that doesn't seem to work, choose a prime $p > n$  and $a,b \in \{0,\dots, p-1\}$ independently and uniformly at random. Now let $h_{a,b}(x) = ax+b \bmod p \bmod m$. Sadly I don't think this is uniform because of the final $\bmod m$.

What can one use instead?

Comment: There are known construction when $n,m$ are powers of 2.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus  What would you do for n, m powers of 2?

Comment: You can find answers in many textbooks and lecture notes.

Comment: See Section 3.5.2 and Problem 3.3 in Salil Vadhan's [monograph](https://people.seas.harvard.edu/~salil/pseudorandomness/basic.pdf) on pseudorandomness.